# Advisor offers phd early during master's thesis

Tags: thesis, early-career

I'm currently two months into writing my master's thesis, which is scheduled to take 12 months. During a conversation with my advisor he offered me a PhD position after I finish my thesis. He mentioned the possibility before already, but this time the offer was very concrete.
I already worked for my current supervisor in the past and did my bachelor's thesis with him and did most of his lectures. I always received good feedback. Since he was a new professor at my university at the time he told me that he wanted to find students to eventually to a phd under his supervision, so the offer didn't completely come out of the blue.
While I'm flattered by this offer it took my by surprise. I like the area of research but I'm still not totally set whether or not I want to pursue a phd (I'm leaning towards yes).
I also didn't look into different universities in my field of study regarding doing a phd yet. I feel a bit rushed by this question as the end of my degree will take at least another 10 months.
So I wanted to ask if my supervisor is early in asking me about a phd or if I am late in thinking about my (academic or not) future? I also wanted to ask for advice how to handle this sort of situation.
It's not like I wouldn't want to say yes, I'm currently at a good university in my field and my supervisor seems to have a good amount of funding. However I want to make an informed decision and somehow "test the market" and see if other supervisors would be interested in me as I did the majority of my "academic" work with my current supervisor.

I already talked to him about the offer and talked about some of my concerns and some details and he seemed to be understanding.

Comment: I've voted to close as it is an entirely personal situation. Examine your priorities along with the advice you get. It is up to you to pick a career and the path to get there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are late in thinking about a PhD programme.

Nor does he seem to be early in asking you about it.

But please note the following:

**1. This may simply be a morale-booster to get you working like a Trojan over the next 12 months.**

A lot of postgrads experience a slump in morale during the first few months of the programme. I don't think offering a tasty carrot 1 year hence is the way to deal with this issue (essentially it's just a matter of getting used to the undergrad to postgrad transition - it usually sort's itself out in the first Spring of the programme) but your supervisor is maybe feeling uneasy about you going off-schedule and offers you this light at the end of the tunnel to buck you up.

**2. It's strange that at the outset he didn't offer you an MPhil initial registration that would lead naturally to conversion to a PhD programme upon satisfactory progress by you . . .**

Funding might not have been available at the outset of course and a large grant may have come in (or he has good signs that it's coming in) in the meantime. Maybe you can discuss a conversion to a PhD programme right now ? But maybe the postgrad system is different in your country.

I think the best thing here is to sit down and honestly explain where you are in this - even at the (small, I think) risk of upsetting the supervisor - rather than treat the relationship like a game and communication with the supervisor like a game strategy.

Naturally, if you are "leaning towards" a PhD at some institution or other at the moment then you should say that. But clearly state that this is a sentiment and not a definite *decision* yet.

Equally, you need to be clear that, if you decide to do a doctorate, you have to consider which Graduate School is best for doing it considering your own ultimate objectives. Do **not** discuss what your ultimate objectives are lest he start trying to build a "salesman's case" for his own School. If asked directly and you feel uncomfortable telling him bluntly to mind his own business, just say you'll be going through all that with your girlfriend in due course.

As you observed, there are two decisions in this matter.

If you are as honest and candid on this matter to your supervisor as he has been with you to date then I think he will value that and let you get on with your decision process.